# Long webpage loading time Selenium VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using selenium VBA for some automation work and its taking a long time loading webpages compared to just using the chrome browser itself.

In the webpage after I successfully login and click on another link inside it will take up to 10-15 seconds to finish loading the page compared to 1 second when using the regular chrome browser.

This is the only current setting I have for the ChromeDriver in VBA

```
Dim Driver As New ChromeDriver
With Driver
    .SetCapability "pageLoadStrategy", "none"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Some webpages have the ability to check if you are a robot or a human, human traffic will always have the priority, best thing I can suggest is an implicit wait

Driver.timeouts.implicitwait = 20000

Time is in milliseconds